# Is there a way to specify which /res folders are auto-generated when creating a new Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, drawable, directory

When I create a new Android project in Eclipse, all of the default folders are auto generated.  This is a nice feature.  However, there are multiple /res folders that I don't need and I would like to disable auto generating them.  For example right now I am only developing for:

10" mdpi tablets, minSdkVersion=16, targetSdkVersion=19

The following /res/drawable and /res/values folders are auto generated:

drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, values, values-v11, values-v14, values-w820dp

And I only need:

drawable-mdpi, values

Is there a way to specify which /res folders are auto-generated when creating a new Android project?

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't. If you don't need them, just delete them; however, I would recommend keeping them incase you need them in the future.